# Isolating URL paths with capturing groups

Tags: regex

Is it possible to have `n` capture groups?

For example,

```
http://www.example.com/first-path
http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path
http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path/third-path
http://www.example.com/something.html
http://www.example.com/first-path?id=5
```

I am trying to capture `first-path` as group 1, `second-path` as group 2, and `third-path` as group 3 using `http:\/\/(.*)\/(?!.*\/$)(.*)`, but it does not split the segments.

No specific programming language being used.

Comment: @wp78de something doesn't seem right: https://regexr.com/3q9ot

Comment: It did not work. I ended up using individual regex's for each path.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using PHP, you could do something like this. The first split removes the leading `http://www.example.com/` part, and the second then splits those values around the `/`:

```
$urls = array('http://www.example.com/first-path',
'http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path',
'http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path/third-path',
'http://www.example.com/something.html',
'http://www.example.com/first-path?id=5');

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $tail = preg_split('#https?://[^/]+/#', $url, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)[0];
    $paths = preg_split('#/#', $tail);
    print_r($paths);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first-path
)
Array
(
    [0] => first-path
    [1] => second-path
)
Array
(
    [0] => first-path
    [1] => second-path
    [2] => third-path
)
Array
(
    [0] => something.html
)
Array
(
    [0] => first-path?id=5
)
```

A similar thing could be done in Javascript:

```
let urls = ['http://www.example.com/first-path',
'http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path',
'http://www.example.com/first-path/second-path/third-path',
'http://www.example.com/something.html',
'http://www.example.com/first-path?id=5'];
console.log(urls.map(s => s.split(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+\//)[1].split(/\//)))
```

Output:

```
Array(5) […]    ​
  0: Array [ "first-path" ]
  1: Array [ "first-path", "second-path" ]
  2: Array(3) [ "first-path", "second-path", "third-path" ]
  3: Array [ "something.html" ]
  4: Array [ "first-path?id=5" ]
```